# using both debugger and Mock results in AttributeError

Tags: python, pdb, python-unittest.mock

I have a piece of unit tests code where at some place `unittest.mock.Mock` is used and I'd like to go through it step by step using debugger. I am using `pdbpp`, but it does not matter in this situation, standard `pdb` and `ipdb` fail on same issue. When debugger encounters `Mock()` call, whole process crashes with traceback below.

Example to replicate (simply run `pytest bug_example.py` and then use `s` (as step) for going through it).

*My question is - why is it happening and if I am able to use both debugger and mock.*

```py
import unittest.mock


def function_that_uses_mock():
    mock = unittest.mock.Mock()
    # anything else
    foo = 42
    return foo


def test_something():
    breakpoint() # can be "import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()" or anything else
    assert function_that_uses_mock() == 42
    # anything else
```

```sh
>       assert function_that_uses_mock() == 42

bug_example.py:13:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
bug_example.py:4: in function_that_uses_mock
    mock = unittest.mock.Mock()
/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py:417: in __new__
    return instance
/usr/lib/python3.10/bdb.py:94: in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_return(frame, arg)
/usr/lib/python3.10/bdb.py:153: in dispatch_return
    self.user_return(frame, arg)
/usr/lib/python3.10/pdb.py:294: in user_return
    self.interaction(frame, None)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdb.py:224: in interaction
    self.print_stack_entry(self.stack[self.curindex])
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdb.py:893: in print_stack_entry
    print(self.format_stack_entry(frame_lineno, prompt_prefix), file=self.stdout)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdb.py:399: in format_stack_entry
    entry = super(Pdb, self).format_stack_entry(frame_lineno, lprefix)
/usr/lib/python3.10/bdb.py:572: in format_stack_entry
    s += reprlib.repr(rv)
/usr/lib/python3.10/reprlib.py:52: in repr
    return self.repr1(x, self.maxlevel)
/usr/lib/python3.10/reprlib.py:62: in repr1
    return self.repr_instance(x, level)
/usr/lib/python3.10/reprlib.py:143: in repr_instance
    return '<%s instance at %#x>' % (x.__class__.__name__, id(x))
/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py:632: in __getattr__
    elif self._mock_methods is not None:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <[AttributeError('_mock_methods') raised in repr()] Mock object at 0x7fe6115b1ba0>, name = '_mock_methods'

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in {'_mock_methods', '_mock_unsafe'}:
>           raise AttributeError(name)
E           AttributeError: _mock_methods

/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py:631: AttributeError
```